# How do I make a progress bar in React JS in fluent FFmpeg edit on Node.js?

Tags: javascript, fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to create a progress bar in editing in fluent-ffmpeg video in node js

I'm using React.js as frontend

[image]
[image]

Comment: kindly don't post screenshots of your code, directly add appropriate code in the question description itself.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.